# How to post data from a partial view using razor pages

Tags: .net-core, partial-views, razor-pages

I'm working on a project that uses razor pages as the UI. i am currently having an issue with posting data from a partial view, my code is shown below

models

```cs
public class CompanyDto
{
   public string Name {get;set}
   public Availability TradingHours {get;set;}
}

public class Availability
{
   public long Id {set; get;}
   public List<AvailablityTime> AvailabilityTimes {get;set;}
}

public class AvailabilityTime
{ 
  public short DayOfWeek {get; set;}
}
```

Razor page code behind

```cs
 public class CreateModel : BasePageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]        
        public CompanyDto command { get; set; }
        
         public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            command = new CompanyDto ();
            command.TradingHours = new Availability();
            
            foreach (var day in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)).OfType<DayOfWeek>().ToList())
            {
                command.TradingHours.AvailabilityTimes.Add(new AvailabityTimeVm
                {
                    DayOfWeek = (short)day
                });
            }

            return Page();
        }
```

create page

```html
@page "/Company/Create"
@model Dashteq.Droplets.Clients.Razor.Pages.Company.CreateModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_CustomThemeLayout.cshtml";
}

<h4>Create</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label asp-for="command.Name" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="command.Name" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="command.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
       <div>
<partial name="_AvailabilityPartial" for="command.TradingHours"/>
<input type="submit" />
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>


Partial View
@model AvailabilitiesVm
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <div class="col-md-8 offset-4 row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h5>Opening</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h5 class="text-sm-left">Closing</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
        @foreach (var item in Model.AvailabilityTimes)
        {
            <li>
                <div class="row ml-2">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.DayOfWeekName)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
```

when i click on the submit button the TradingHours field of the CompanyDto is null. Any idea on how to to get the data from the partial view into the bound property?

Comment: maybe this sentence in doc. `[BindProperty] should not be used on models containing properties that should not be changed by the client` ? https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: or try change partial to <partial name="_AvailabilityPartial" for="Model.TradingHours"/> or <partial name="_AvailabilityPartial" for="Model.command.TradingHours"/>

Comment: @daremachine using for="Model.command.TradingHours" throws a compile time error..

Comment: instead of using the  @foreach (var item in Model.AvailabilityTimes)
        {
            <li>
                <div class="row ml-2">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.DayOfWeekName)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>  had to use the for loop